# drupal 7.21 views exposed form

Tags: 7, views

The question is - what may be the reason for exposed form to not be working/showing in a block? Thanks so much - hope someone has an idea about that.

Comment: Could you post more information ? Do you have "Exposed form in a block" on ? Posting a screenshot of the Advanced pane of the Views UI would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have chosen 'block' as the display rather than 'page', you have to set 'Use Ajax' to 'Yes' in the Advanced options (See this issue on Drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/1115782#comment-4384348):

[image]

Comment: This is not true. I have done this with Ajax off.

Comment: Interesting. I had the same problem yesterday and setting `Use AJAX` to yes fixed the problem.

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: Well, I set `Use AJAX` to `no` as a test and my contextual filter disappeared again.  Using Views 7.x-3.5

Comment: Please see the following issue on DO http://drupal.org/node/1115782#comment-4384348

Comment: This issue is fixed the patch was commited on 25th of April 2012! Anyways, thanks for the link. didn't notice there was such problem.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the patch file, it doesn't actually change the functionality, it just issues a warning that you need AJAX turned on - `drupal_set_message(t('For block views, "Use AJAX" must be set to "Yes" for exposed filters to be displayed.'),'error',FALSE);`

Comment: Weird. I just did a test exposed filter: http://imgur.com/PJFKKcD 
You will see the `action` is set to the page display's URL and method is GET (not using Ajax).

Comment: It'd be cool to see how you managed to do it without AJAX, maybe post the steps as an answer?